# Socket.io only emit messages on both server and client reload

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-native, sockets, socket.io

I have this pending issue for days now. I am building an Expo React Native app with Node.js backend and MYSQL with Sequelize for database. The app has a messaging feature which I am to handle with `socket.io`.
On both server and client reload, Socket.io emit messages instantly. If you as a user leaves the chatroom and enters a new chatroom, you will not receive the instant messages until you reload both server and client. This is just how it works now. Strangely, when I used `console.log()` on the data coming from `socket.io` data when a new message is sent, I get to see the emitted message. However, it simply can't be displayed on the screen. I have done everything that I can think of. I dont know if the problem is from React Native or the server side.
Here is sample of the code:

server side:

```
import * as socketio from "socket.io";
 export const io = new socketio.Server();

  const socketapi = {
   io: io
   };
  
   let users: userSocketAttributes[] = [];

      io.on('connection', (socket)=>{
        console.log('A user connected via socket.io');
        socket.on("addUser", userId=>{
        const userValues = {
            userId: userId as string,
            socketId: socket.id
          }
           addUser(userValues);
           io.emit("getUsers", users)
         });
              socket.on("sendMessage", async (messageAttributes: socketMessageAttributes, )=>{
        const user = findUser(messageAttributes.recieverId);
        
        const authToken = JWT_Helper_verify(messageAttributes.auth) as JwtPayload;
                    
       try {
        const userid = await CreateCustomer.findOne({where:{id: authToken?.id}});
        const support = await CreateCustomer.findOne({where: {user_username: 'support'}});

        
        io.to(user?.socketId as string).emit("getMessage", messageAttributes)
       } catch (error) {
        return console.log(error)
       }
        })
        //disconect
        socket.on("disconnect", ()=>{
        console.log("disconnected");
        removeUser(socket.id);
        io.emit("getUsers", users)

         })
         })
```

server.js

```
import socketapi from "./socket";
 
  const server = http.createServer(app);

  socketapi.io.attach(server)
   const startServer = ()=>{

   server.listen(port, ()=>{
    console.log(`server is listening on ${port}`)
  })
 }
startServer()
```

Client side:

```
  const socket = useRef()
  //fetch messages from database
   const fetchMessages = async()=>{

        try {
         const res = await axios.get(`${BASE_URL}/conversation/${data?.conversation?.id}`, { 
         withCredentials: true,
             headers:{authorization: `Bearer ${token}`}})
                setChatMessages(res?.data?.CreateMessageModels);
               
        } catch (error) {
         
        }
     }

     //users to exchange messages
 useEffect(()=>{
   
    socket.current = io(socket_URL);
    socket.current.emit('addUser', userDetails?.role === 'support'? data?.conversation?.recieverId: userDetails?.id);
    socket.current.on("getUsers", users =>{
       console.log(users, 'socket')
   }); 
   
}, [data?.conversation?.id])

//useEffect for fetching messages from database
 useEffect(()=>{
    fetchMessages()
}, [])

//Listens to socket.io emitted messages
  useEffect(()=>{
   
    socket.current.on("getMessage", (item)=>{
        
        if(data?.conversation?.id == item?.conversationId){
           
            setChatMessages([...chatMessages, item])
        }    
    })
   });
```

What can I do to fix this?

Comment: Your code opens a new socket.io connection on conversation id change. You need to use something like context api to connect ws once. then use it every where. also you need to return socket.off in the main useeffect hook ( component will unmount )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I use `socket.io` client in my `REACT` app.

```js
const WSAPI_URI = "wss://example.org"
export const wsContext = React.createContext({} as any);

export default function WsProvider({
  children,
}: {
  children: ReactNode;
}): ReactElement {
  const [webSocket, setWebSocket] = React.useState<any>(null);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    const socket = io(WSAPI_URI, {
      query: {
        accesstoken: localStorage.getItem("@myapp/access_token"),
      },
      reconnection: true,
      transports: ["websocket"],
    });
    setWebSocket(socket);
  }, []);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (!webSocket) return;

    return () => webSocket.off();
  }, [webSocket]);

  return <wsContext.Provider value={webSocket}>{children}</wsContext.Provider>;
}

function SomeComponent() {
  const ws = useContext(wsContext);

  useEffect(() => {
    ws.on(`MYTOPIC`, (data: string) => {
       // my logic
    });
    return () => {
      ws?.off(`MYTOPIC`);
    };
  }, [ws])

  return <></>
}

function MyAPP() {
  return <WsProvider>
      <SomeComponent/>
  </WsProvider>
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this resolved my issue. You saved a soul.

Comment: @kingsJayson you are welcome. The key point about ```socket.io``` is different versions are different. There's no backward compatibility in major versions. If you use version 3 on the server side, you have to use v3 on the client side, and so on.